# Squid proxy server returning error

Tags: squid, mikrotik, transparent-proxy

I have designed a topology which has an external proxy server (192.168.239.152) and a Mikrotik Router (192.168.239.151).
The MikroTik router connected with a LAN and enables internet connection to LAN PCs. The LAN PCs has IP from the block 192.168.1.0/24.

I want traffic (HTTP, HTTPS) from LAN PCs to go through the proxy server, so that I don't need to configure Browser manually to use proxy settings. For this I have created DST-NAT into MikroTik Router in following method:

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj3Ic.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNGsR.png)

Traffic from LAN PCs going through proxy server (Squid) but it's showing an error like below:

[Squid Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o6jn.png)

What goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the policy routing, not the DNAT, see https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/mikrotik_transparent_squid/index.html

Answer (score 0):

@Rafael

I already followed that method and it returns same error. I think it has something to do with Squid setup. I have been suggested that I need to set squid as transparent proxy. So I set following:

```
http_port 3128 transparent
```

in /etc/squid/squid.conf file
but after that squid service failed to start!